# How to validate jQuery UI combobox values with jQuery Validation Plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

I've added jQuery UI combobox with remote source to my form. Now, I am trying to validate that with jQuery Validation Plugin (only values from the list are allowed, field is mandatory).

I've tried standard approach:

```
 $("#myform").validate({
    focusInvalid: false,
    focusCleanup: true,
    rules: {
      cbCountry: { // combobox
        required: true
      }
```

But still empty values are allowed. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: I've tried to follow @Mike_Laird's advice below and I've found that my custom method

```
$.validator.addMethod('validComboboxValue', function (value) {
},
...
```

even not called when applied to jQuery UI combobox. But when I assign the same method to standard text input, it is called.

Comment: Is `cbCountry` the name of the underlying `select` or the generated `input`? Could you post the code you're working with?

Comment: @Andrew, cbCountry is the `select`. Here is the sample code - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/8kLbf/ (`cbCity` is used there instead of `cbCountry`). However, validation doesn't work properly for me at jsfiddle.

Comment: Both options of the `<select>` have a value (0/1) so i guess the _required_ rule is always passed, it's never null/empty.

Comment: @DidierG., but actually nothing can be chosen...

Comment: @LA_: Any reason you have to use a `select`? I know the combobox example uses one, but you could just use an `autocomplete` that looks like a combobox. The validation may be simpler that way.

Comment: @Andrew, yes, I need combobox - user can choose there most popular values (instead of typing value into autocomplete field).

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea is to set values on each of the select options, and then write a custom validator method to check the option values. Something like the following custom method will make some selection only from the select dropdown required.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
"selectComboboxCheck",
function (value, element)
    {
    if (element.value === "0") {return false;}
    else return true;
    }
"Required - select an option."
);
```

Put class="selectComboboxCheck"  in the select tag to trigger this method.
The select options should look something like

```
<option value = "1">1</option>
```

Comment: It could be simplified to `if (value === "0") { ...`

Answer (score 3):

validate.js needs the "name" on the tag, when you use jqueryui autocomplete combobox.
The generated code does not have both an `id` and `name` attribute, so they need to be added as needed.

In the `_create` function for the combobox, you need to add:

```
select = this.element.hide(),
select_id = select.attr('id'),
selected = select.children(":selected"),
```

and:

```
input = $("<input>")
.attr('id', select_id + '_combobox')
.attr('name', select_id + '_combobox')
.appendTo(wrapper)
```

Such, given HTML like this:

```
<select id="dropDownlist">
  <option...
</select>
```

The `autocomplete-combobox` will generate the required `input` element with the `id` and `name` attributes set to `dropDownlist_combobox`

with this i have full control over this autogenerated htmls tag from jqueryui-autocomplete-combobox
You can then apply the validation rules to the `input` element (`dropDownlist-combobox`)
This will look something like:

```
$('#dropDownlist_combobox').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    messages: {
        required: 'Please enter your combobox'
    }
});
```

and voila :)

Using this, however, you will get an issue with the error message being shown between the `input` tag and the "dropdown" button. To fix this, you will need some additional code:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.context.id.indexOf('_combobox') == -1)
            error.insertAfter(element);
        else
            error.appendTo(element.parent());
    }
});
```

All the code for the example is available at http://jsfiddle.net/XhU78/

I hope works for you :)

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues here. First - you have to use element's name, not identifier. Second: if I understand correctly - you think you allow empty `<select>` values, but it's not like that. Select is populated correctly after autocomplete, but when you pass an empty value in `<input id="acId">` (e.q. delete content and hit ESC) the change is not propagated to `<select>` that holds content assigned before `<input id="acId">` was cleared.

Long story short - you should either check not in select, but automaticaly created input, or propagate somehow the empty value to select.

Using your fiddle I tested the first approach : http://jsfiddle.net/RRH6t/1/

```
//changes made

//HTML:
<select id="cbCity" name="cbCityName" style="display:none">

//JS:
var input = this.input = $('<input id="acId" name="acName">')
...
$("#fAddTeacher").validate({
    debug : true,            // for debugging
    rules: {
        cbCityName: {
            required: true
        },
        acName : {
            required : true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new custom method like this

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("selectComboboxCheck",
        function (value, element)
            {
                if ($(element).find(":selected").val() == -1) {
                    return false; 
                }
                else return true;
            },
            "Required"
        );
```

and add create the select box like this:

```
<select id="dropDownlist" class="selectComboboxCheck">
  <option value="-1">Select something</option>
  <option value="1">Car</option>
  <option value="2">Plane</option>
</select>
```

Now when you select "Select something" validation will not pass, and otherwise it will.
(tested with jquery 1.9.1)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old topic, but I just had to do more or less the same (though with a static source). The only problem with checking the select's value is that the Validation plugin filters out hidden elements, and the Combobox code has conveniently hidden the original select. However, nothing stops us from telling the Validator to consider all elements, even hidden ones:

```
$("#form").validate({
    ignore: ""
});
```

Ignore is a selector to filter out unneeded elements and by default equals `:hidden`. You can just as well supply that in a call to `$.validator.setDefaults()` and have it work for any validator instance. This works when submitting the form with a `required` and a `min` attributes, perhaps some more effort will be needed to have this work on selecting (like triggering a `focusout` event).

**UPDATE**

To get it to validate also on value change instead of only on form submit is a bit trickier, but boils down to the following:

1. Actually only `required` attribute is needed, not the `min` one.
2. Combobox code needs to be changed to accept option with an empty value. Since it is just an example to JQueryUI, this should not be a problem.
3. Have the first option in select be one with an empty value.
4. Have Combobox trigger a `focusout` event on state change (`autocompleteselect`, `_removeIfInvalid`).

Comment: Oh yeah, and you will have to implement your own errorPlacement function, as by default in would go right after the main element, so it will screw the layout.